# Using 'case' in a select query sqlalchemy throwing exception

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to construct this sql query into sqlalchemy:

```
select distinct
    processed_by_user_uuid,
    sum(case when audited_result_uuid = PASSED_RESULT_UUID then 1 else 0 end) as "passed",
    sum(case when audited_result_uuid <> PASSED_RESULT_UUID then 1 else 0 end) as "failed",
    count(distinct processed_using) as "total audits"
from audit
where
    audited_at is not null
    and processed_at > [start_time]
    and processed_at < [end_time]
group by 1
```

My attempt:

```
query = Session.query(audit_table).with_entities(
    audit_table.c.processed_by_user_uuid,
    func.sum(
        case([audit_table.c.audited_result_uuid == PASSED_RESULT_UUID, 1], else_=0)
    ).label('passed'),
    func.sum(
        case([audit_table.c.audited_result_uuid != PASSED_RESULT_UUID, 1], else_=0)
    ).label('failed'),
    func.count(distinct(audit_table.c.processed_using)).label('total audits')
).filter(
    audit_table.c.audited_at is not None,
    audit_table.c.processed_at > start_time,
    audit_table.c.processed_at < end_time
).group_by(
    1
)
```

When I try this, I get the exception:

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

From some digging, it is unhappy about this line:

```
func.sum(
    case([audit_table.c.audited_result_uuid == PASSED_RESULT_UUID, 1], else_=0)
).label('passed')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not using the [`case(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) properly - you need to put your condition in a tuple of `(condition, value)` instead so that:

```
case([audit_table.c.audited_result_uuid == PASSED_RESULT_UUID, 1], else_=0)
```

becomes:

```
case([(audit_table.c.audited_result_uuid == PASSED_RESULT_UUID, 1)], else_=0)
```

The same applies for the other `case` statement.

---

Furthermore, your filter condition `audit_table.c.audited_at is not None` will not result in the query you are trying to build. This expression will evaluate to `boolean` value of `True` and therefore will generate a *truthy* `WHERE` clause such as `WHERE 1=1` (or nothing at all).
Instead you should use `audit_table.c.audited_at != None`. The PEP-8 checks will complain, but this is how it should be used with sqlalchemy.